# How to sort view results by translated node title when using entity translation in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, multilingual

I'm having trouble getting my view to sort by the translated title of the node. I'm running drupal 7 with the entity translation and title modules enabled. I have a content type called "muscle" and I've translated all the English titles into German. I have created a view which lists all of the muscles titles in alphabetical order. The view works well in both the English and German pages, but on the German pages, the titles are sorted by the English so they appear jumbled.

This is the SQL code from the view:

```
    SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS
       field_data_title_field_node_entity_type
    FROM {node} node
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('muscle')) ))
    ORDER BY node_title ASC
```

I've been searching for a solution but I haven't been able to find out what I'm doing wrong. I do see that the node table does not include the translated titles so I think there would need to be a join. I also see that when I'm editing the view, I don't have an option for choosing the translated entity for sorting.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the join in views UI under relationships in the advanced section.